# Makefile in packages with UNIX commands and latexmk?

Tags: dtx, makefile

What are the rules regarding writing Makefiles to be part of CTAN packages?

I would like to include a Makefile in a package I wrote. The package is in `.dtx` format with its `.ins` file embedded.

When I run `make`, it generates all package files, including `.tex` examples. Of course it also compiles the documentation in `PDF` format.

When I run `make all`, it behaves the same way as make but also all `.tex` examples are compiled.

`make clean` removes all generated files except the `.cls` and the documentation. `make distclean` removes also these files.

1) There is a problem distributing a package with a Makefile` that behaves this way?

This Makefile includes UNIX syntax and UNIX commands, in particular I have shell variable pointed to /bin/sh, which is the default:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
```

Also I do use `for` command to compile everything and `grep` and `sed` to extract the version number from `.dtx` file.

2) It is OK distributing the package with such a Makefile? MiKTeX users won't be able to compile anything. Or... are `Makefile`s always useless to Windows users?

3) How safe is using `latexmk` to compile everything? This Perl script is present on MiKTeX basic installation? I'm running Debian and I've it installed but I don't know if it is a common package on LaTeX distributions...

4) What is the best place to put `makeindex` lines (for change history and index)? in `Makefile` between two `pdflatex` (or `latexmk`...) runs or inside the `.ins` file?

If I let `latexmk` run `makeindex`, the resulting `PDF` has overlapped entries on index, and no change history appears (no `.gls` file is created), so I must put `makeindex` lines by hand on `Makefile` or inside the `.dtx` (inside it embedded `.ins`).

Comment: Why do you need to distribute the Makefile? It's common to send only the 'business end' to CTAN with the assumption that most people will get it _via_ their TeX system (which have their own build scripts) or will download and build manually.

Comment: BTW, `make` is runnable on Windows but is non-standard, and I'd probably work on the basis that most people with `make` there have Cygwin or similar Unix-like' tools available. So for most 'end user' MiKTeX people the answer is 'no, not useful' (write an equivalent `make.bat` file if you want parallel features).

Comment: Also BTW, CTAN will certainly accept Makefiles: there's one for `beamer`, for example, largely a 'historical' thing!

Comment: @JosephWright I don't really need it. That means TeX system maintainers won't run any `Makefile`? In this case I'm not interested in writing the `.bat` equivalent. We should send the compiled documentation in the package we upload to CTAN, so there is no problem with it because what they post in `.zip` and in the browsable web folder has the exactly the same `PDF` documentation we sent. What I don't know is if TeX distributors recompiles something. This `pdf` documentations need to be compiled again after one example.pdf because this example is included in the main documentation as a sample...

Comment: @JosephWright ...if the sample wasn't compiled, the main documentation warns to the `.log` but doesn't produces any error (I'm using `\IfFileExists{example.pdf}`). I would not desire that the documentation were compiled in the "wrong" way in some TeX distributions. That's the rationale for creating my Makefile. If TeX systems always includes the pdf documentation as-is, there is no need to make public my Makefile.

Comment: @EmilioLazo I don't think TeX distributions compile anything not provided by the CTAN upload. For simple uploads, I think they run `tex` on the `ins` file to extract from the `dtx` the package file; even if the `dtx` is structured so that running `tex` directly on it is possible and does the extraction. They do not recompile `pdf` documentation already in the upload. Furthermore if your submission has a `package.tds.zip` included, that's what (at least TeXLive) will take as is. At least in my experience, but others surely know more.

Comment: @jfbu Ok. Thanks, also to @JosephWright. Then I will upload the package without Makefile and with the `pdf` documentation in the upload -as CTAN requires-, so the `pdf` will be propagated as-is in TeX distributions as you pointed out. I think submitting a `tds` is _in_my_case_ not necessary because of the complexity of my package. It only has a `cls`, a `def` and some examples `tex` to be compiled later in a straightforward way (details are in the documentation)... Having the `ins` file separated from the `dtx` can represent an advantage to TeX distributions or to somebody?

Comment: @EmilioLazo I never investigated the issue of the `ins` as I always provide it, although all my `dtx` are self-extracting. Regarding the `pdf` I just checked for confirmation on two of my packages, and when opening the files in `Adobe Reader` and checking the creation date, it is exactly the same as the ones of my uploads (the file modification dates differ, thus I needed to open them in a pdf viewer to check the info fields). Thus, there was no re-compilation of the `pdf`.

Comment: @jfbu, `etoc` is yours? I did check it right now. Your `dtx` generates the `ins` (is self-extracting, like mine), but the package in CTAN includes the `ins` file. I didn't do this way because CTAN upload page states that they do not wish to hold files that can be easily generated from an included file, but the pair `ins` <-> `dtx` might be an exception to this rule. As a side note regarding `etoc`: I'm working on another package with a bilingual _simultaneous_ documentation in columns with `paracol`. E.

Comment: @EmilioLazo I agree that the rule of  CTAN probably does not apply to `ins` files because in the old days there were (I think) no self-extracting `dtx` (I don't know who started the habit). Furthermore I pay attention to the fact that extraction is possible using `tex`, not `pdftex` which has the `e-TeX` extensions, the `ins` file should always be compilable with pure `tex` (the `dtx` also is for `etoc`). Regarding `etoc`, simultaneous bilingual would be a challenge because of all the table of contents of the `doc` itself which are generated on the fly.

Comment: @EmilioLazo there is an intrinsic limitation to extraction from the `dtx` which is that TeX can not write a file without extension (it always adds a default `.tex` if no extension is given). This is a difficulty for a `README` or a `Makefile` for example. Besides, for makefiles there is the additional problem about tabs. The suitable catcode must be set.